# Fabric.js line moving and scaling respective to another object

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have tried to move and scale the line as equals of another line using programmatic way by pressing the button while clicking the button first time(with out changing the reference object position) its happening as my expectation, but when I am moved the object and pressed second time it's not happening as I expect.

### Code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid red"/>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="changePosition()" value="Change Possition"/>
```

**Script**

```
var canvas=new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var points=[100,100,300,100],
    points1=[300,200,400,200],line,line1;
    line=new fabric.Line(points,{
                    stroke: 'black',
                    strokeWidth: 3,                    
                    selectable: true
                });
    canvas.add(line);

    line1=new fabric.Line(points1,{
                    stroke: 'black',
                    strokeWidth: 3,                    
                    selectable: true});
    canvas.add(line1);


function changePosition()
{
   //canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(0));
    line.set(line1);
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.calcOffset();
    line.setCoords();
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thirumalaimurugan/p9jyu/)

How I can move the line where where the line1 is placed?

Comment: @kangax please help in this

Comment: Did you try to debug line internal data before and after the button was pressed?